# Access a sector from USB flash memory in linux

Tags: c, linux, fat

I am studying the FAT32 manual, now i want to write a program to browse the device. How to read a specific sector of the device, i do not want to load the entire device as a file into memory, please suggest some system call's to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the block device in `/dev/`, then your system calls are `open`, `lseek`, and `read`. Higher level stuff like `fopen`, `fseek`, and `fread` will work too. [Everything is a file.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file)

Comment: Thanks, wumpus, forgot the bascis... :)